# Don't publish sub modules to docker

Tags: sbt-native-packager

I have two Projects:

```
val common = Project("common", file("common"))
        .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
val frontend = Project("frontend", file("frontend"))
        .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
        .dependsOn(common).aggregate(common)
```

Now, I want to do a docker build, which works out of the box, but when I do

```
sbt "project frontend" docker:publish
```

it will publish both modules to docker. How can I prevent pushing the `common` module to my docker registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either remove the `aggregate(commons)` or override the `docker:publishLocal` task like this:

```
...
 . settings(
   publishLocal in Docker := {}
 )
```

Comment: since I need `aggregate()` for executing the test-task, I'll go with your suggestion to override the task. SBT is sometimes more easy, than it looks like.

Comment: SBT really improved dramatically since 0.13.x. It's not the beast it once was.